# ARMv7 Assembly Language : How to reverse a char array and output it to another char array

Tags: c, assembly, arm, armv7

I am a beginner tinkering with ARM7 Assembly Language programming.

I am trying to implement a simple function in ARM assembly that takes a char array, reverses it, and stores it into another char array of equal length.

I have included both my C code and ARM7 Assembly Language code below. However, my code doesn't output the correct reversed string; which is probably due to my ASM instructions. I am running Linux with a 32 bit machine.

reverseString.s (code below)

```
.global reverseString

.text

reverseString:
    MOV R2, R1          @store strIn[0] into R2
    PUSH {R4-R6}        @save regs
    MOV R4, #0          @R4 will be strIn_len reg, store 0 for count

@finds the length of the strIn arr
strlen_loop:
    LDR R3, [R2], #1    @increment through strIn arr
    ADD R4, R4, #1      @count the no. of chars
    CMP R3, #0          @check if null term hit
    BNE strlen_loop     @if yes leave, else cont.

@string reversal loop
    MOV R0, R2          @movs ptr of strOut to last element
loop:
    CMP R4, #0          @makes sure count !=0
    BEQ loop_end        @if yes, end loop
    LDR R5, [R1], #1    @incr. address of strIn in R1 and put into R5
    STR R5, [R0], #-1   @store the value at address in strOut
    SUB R4, R4, #1      @decrement counter var
    B loop

loop_end:
    POP {R4-R6} @restore regs
    BX LR
```

reverseString.c (code below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern void reverseString(char strOut[], const char strIn[]);

#define COUNT 6

int main()
{ 
  const char strIn[COUNT] = "candy";
  char strOut[COUNT];
  reverseString(strOut, strIn);
  printf("%s\r\n", strOut);
  return 0;
}
```

compiled on command line using

```
gcc -g -o reverseString reverseString.s reverseString.c
./reverseString
```

[image: output]

Comment: What is the output you're getting? Have you stepped through this in the debugger? Why is `strIn` const when you are going to change it?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did use the debugger and step through the entire code. After checking the registers, they decrement and increment properly. It seems that there might be junk in the register once I access it. Since my output looks like the above garbage. Also `strIn` is supposed to be unchanged. I simply want to access the elements (not change their values).

Comment: You may pass the src pointer as const, but you cannot declare the original array as const if you are going to change it with scanf. You might find it helpful to play around with some C code compiled to ARM. It may help to work out the logic in a potentially more familiar language. https://godbolt.org/z/e1uq_Q  Since you're copying 1 byte at a time you may need to use those specific instructions.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This was an oversight on my part and it should not be declared as const if I am to use scanf. I will correct this and make it const. Also, thank you for the link to that website it is very helpful.

Comment: Are you trying for ARM7 or ARMv7?

Comment: I believe ARM7. Yes, this is a relatively older processor core. However, its because I am programming on a RasPi3.

Answer (score 0):

Try an experiment. Initialize `strOut` to something, and after the call to `reverseString` print both `strIn` and `strOut`. Observe the somewhat funny output.

Now, in

```
        MOV R0, R2          @movs ptr of strOut to last element
```

Last element of exactly what?

`R2`, in the `strlen_loop` above, traversed the `strIn`, and at this point contains the address of its end. Now `R0` also contains that address, and the rest of the code has no relevance to `strOut`. It attempts to reverse `strIn`.

This move is not only harmful but redundant. Just copy from `[R2], #-1` to `[R0], #1`.

Comment: Thank you for your time. When you say copy from `[R2], #-1` to `R0], #1` which line is this? Is it `STR R5, [R0], #-1`?